# Several configurations (@Meta.OCD interface) in the same component

Tags: configuration, liferay, osgi, liferay-7

I have a component MyComponent that needs to access AConfiguration and BConfiguration:

my.MyComponent:

```
@Component(
    configurationPid = "[my.AConfiguration,my.BConfiguration]"
)
public class MyComponent {
    @Activate
    @Modified
    protected void activate(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        _aConfiguration = ConfigurableUtil
            .createConfigurable(AConfiguration.class, properties);
        _bConfiguration = ConfigurableUtil
            .createConfigurable(BConfiguration.class, properties);
    }

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("A:" + _sConfiguration.valueA());
        System.out.println("B:" + _sConfiguration.valueB());
    }
}
```

my.AConfiguration:

```
@Meta.OCD(
    id = "my.AConfiguration"
)
public interface AConfiguration {
    @Meta.AD(deflt = "6")
    public long valueA();
}
```

my.BConfiguration:

```
@Meta.OCD(
    id = "my.BConfiguration"
)
public interface BConfiguration {
    @Meta.AD(deflt = "6")
    public long valueB();
}
```

**Problem**: Configuring valueA and valueB to `7` using Liferay's configuration UI has no effect, `MyComponent.hello()` still sees the default value `6`.

What am I doing wrong?
What is the correct way to make my component use configuration information from several configuration interfaces?

*Use case: My component does some business processing and saves results to a remote server. There is one configuration interface containing the business processing settings, and one configuration interface containing the URL to the remote server.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of the `configurationPid` attribute on the `@Component` annotation is wrong. It should be:

```
configurationPid = { "my.AConfiguration", "my.BConfiguration" }
```

This creates a String-array value with two entries, `my.AConfiguration` and `my.BConfiguration`. Instead you have used:

```
configurationPid = "[my.AConfiguration,my.BConfiguration]"
```

... which creates a *single* String with the literal value `[my.AConfiguration,my.BConfiguration]`, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Oh, interesting! So using several configurations is OK, if using this syntax? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This is the standard Java syntax for creating a String-array value in an annotation attribute. Unfortunately Java creates ambiguity because it allows for a single-entry array to be created without the braces. That is, `configurationPid = "foo"` is equivalent to `configurationPid = { "foo" }`